# swift: вызов функции

Tags: swift

Я новичок в Xcode, поэтому прошу не судить строго.
Есть функция c парсингом JSON

```
func getJsonData() -> Int {
    let url=URL(string:"http://..............")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Невозможно подключиться к серверу")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    if let jsonData = myJson["data"] as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        if let abonent = jsonData["abonentid"]
                        {
                            let iAbonentid=abonent
                            print("Вернуть значение для проверки")
                            print(iAbonentid)
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
    print("Результат из функции")
    return iAbonentid

}
```

Есть вызов функции

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let abonent = getJsonData()
    print("Проверка вызова")
    print(abonent)
}
```

Результат возвращается в следующем виде:

```
Результат из функции
Проверка вызова
0
Вернуть значение для проверки
113786
```

Судя по print программа не заходит в функцию при её вызове, а заходит уже после отработки вызова. Почему так?

Comment: Принтни, что там в catch происходит

Comment: Еще интересно следующее: у тебя есть локальная переменная iAbonentid, здесь `let iAbonentid=abonent ` но ты ее возвращаешь вне области видимости.

Comment: Еще будет не лишним почитать о [асинхронных Closure](https://appventure.me/2015/06/19/swift-try-catch-asynchronous-closures/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что `URLSession.shared.dataTask` это [Closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html). К тому же выполняется асинхронно, то есть в фоновом потоке. Closure - аналог [блока в Objective-C](http://macbug.ru/cocoa/objc6).

Например, как определить Closure:

```
let divide = {(val1: Int, val2: Int) -> Int in 
   return val1 / val2 
}
let result = divide(200, 20)
println (result)
```

Пример асинхронной функции возвращающей Closure:

```
func makeRequest(withBlock block: @escaping (Int)->()) {

    let url=URL(string:"http://..............")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Невозможно подключиться к серверу")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    if let jsonData = myJson["data"] as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        if let abonent = jsonData["abonentid"]
                        {
                            print("Вернуть значение для проверки")
                            if let ab = abonent as? Int {
                              block(ab)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    //TODO: ALWAYS CATCH ERRORS!!!!
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

А используешь её потом таким образом:

```
makeRequest { (abonent) in
    print(abonent)
}
```